# Referencing Numbered Variables and Arrays

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, class, actionscript

I am pretty new to AS3 and am trying to get an advanced inventory system going. I have 3 players and 3 classes: `PlayerStats1`, `PlayerStats2`, and `PlayerStats3`. Inside each of these classes I have an array. This array contains the inventory for each player. The arrays are all named `inventory`. I also have a variable that determines whose inventory is opened. This variable is just called `turn`. Now what if I wanted to find out and display what was in Player2's inventory slot 5 (the fifth value in `PlayerStats2.inventory`)? How would I go about doing that with a simple code? Something like `gotoAndStop(PlayerStat + turn.inventory[4]);`. Of course the code probably looks a lot bigger than that.

Comment: Slot number 5 : `my_array[5]` is the sixth value of an array.  The first one is numbered 0.

Comment: I forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
class A {

    private var playDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public function addPlayer(playerId:int, player:PlayStats):void {
         playDict[playerId] = player;
   }

   public function getInventory(playerId:int, invertoryIndex:int):Object {
        var player:PlayStats = playDict[playerId] as PlayStats;

        if (player) {
           if (player.inventory) {
               return player.inventory[invertoryIndex];
           } else {
               return null;
           }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
   }

}
```

PlayStats is base class of  PlayStats1,  PlayStats2,  PlayStats3.
PlayStats1,  PlayStats2,  PlayStats3 could add target objects to its own invertory

```
public class  PlayStats {

   public var inventory:Array = [];
}
```

Comment: I'm really new to AS3. Do I have to make a new class for this to work? I have no idea what is happening in this code. I have a movie clip that displays the item in the inventory slot. Each item has a number which is added to the inventory array. I need this movie clip to goto the frame that is equal to whatever is the fifth number in whoever's inventory to be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean  PlayStats1, PlayStats2, PlayStats3 each has 5 frames, and you want a function make one of them go to the target frame?

Comment: PlayStats1, PlayStats2, and PlayStats3 are all individual classes. I will have multiple movie clips, but for now I'm focusing on the movie clip for inventory slot 5. Inside the movie clip is a bunch of frames. Each frame has the illustration of an object. This movie clip should be able to find whose turn it is and then find whatever is in there fifth inventory slot then goto it.